# How to link two nasm source files

Tags: compiler-construction, assembly, linker, nasm, extern

I've got a file that defines very basic IO functions and I want to create another file that uses this file.

Is there a way to link these two files up?

prints.asm:

```
os_return:
    ;some code to return to os
print_AnInt:
    ;some code to output an int, including negatives - gets param from stack
print_AChar:
    ;some code to output a char - gets param from stack
```

usingPrintTest.asm:

```
main:
   push qword 'a'
   call print_AChar ;gets this from prints.asm somehow (that's my question)
   call os_return   ;and this too..
```

Note these aren't the actual files... They're just used to explain my problem :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - you just need to use the linker.  Assemble each of your files:

```
nasm -o prints.o prints.asm
nasm -o usingPrintTest.o usingPrintTest.asm
```

You can then pass the output objects to your linker.  Something like:

```
gcc -o myProgramName prints.o usingPrintTest.o
```

Using `gcc` as the linker driver can solve some funny business with linking the OS libraries you need for your program to run.  You might need to make some declarations in `usingprintTest.asm` to let it know that `print_Achar` and `os_return` are going to be defined elsewhere - in `nasm`, you'll use the `extern` assembler directive:

```
extern print_Achar
extern os_return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. By the time we did some intense googling we came up with the answer SECONDS before you got it :P