# Referencing symbols of code/data loaded separately to another part of memory

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, include, nasm

I have two nasm-syntax assembly files, let's say `a.asm` and `b.asm`.
They will need to be assembled into two **seperate** binary files, `a.bin` and `b.bin`.
On startup `a.bin` will be loaded by another program to a fixed location in memory (`0x1000`).
`b.bin` will be loaded later to an arbitrary location in memory.
`b.bin` will use some of the functions defined in `a.bin`.
*PROBLEM:* `b.bin` does not know where the functions are located in `a.bin`

*Why do they need to be seperate?* They're unrelated, keeping `b.bin` (and many more files) and `a.bin` in one file would defeat the purpose of a file system.

*Why not `%include` it?* Memory usage, `a.bin` is quite a large set of functions taking up lots of memory, and because of the 640kb memory limit in x86 real mode i can't really afford to have this in memory for every file that needs it.

**possible solution 1:** just hardcode the locations.
**problem:** what if i change something minor at the very start of `a.bin`? I'll need to update all pointers to stuff after it, and that's not handy.

**possible solution 2:** keep track of the function locations in one file, and `%include` that.
This is probably what i'll do if i have no other options. I might even be able to automatically generate this file if nasm can generate easy-to-parse symbol listings, otherwise it's still too much work.

**possible solution 3:** keep a table in memory of where the functions are located, instead of the functions themselves. This also has the added benefit of backwards compatibility, if i do decide to change `a.bin`, all things using it don't have to change along with it.
**problem:** indirect call is really slow and takes up lot's of disk space, though really this is a minor issue. The table will also take up some space in disk and memory though.
My idea was to add this later, as a library or something like that. So everything that's compiled along with `a.bin` can call it faster by using direct calls and things that are compiled seperately as eg. applications can use the table for slower but safer access to `a.bin`.

**TLDR;**
how to include labels from another asm file so that they can be called w/o including the actual code in the final assembled file?

Comment: possible solution 4: use a (hardcoded) jumptable to the functions

Comment: @Tommylee2k, isn't that basically what i described in solution 3? ofcourse the whole table is generated at compile-time (or assembly-time in this case), but there is still overhead in memory (the table needs to be stored somewhere), reading it and calling indirectly.

Comment: the table could have a fix position somewhere (e.g. starting directly at $1000 (next at $1003, $1006, $1009 etc, while $1000 holds "jump func1", $1003 "jmp func2"), where a.bin will be loaded to), or you implement a single jump-in point, and determine the function to call by setting a register (like int10 or 21 does)

Comment: @Tommylee2k, all these solutions still have runtime overhead while an assembly-time solution does exist, i'm looking for an easier or automated way to do it at assembly-time so i can have maximum speed on ancient hardware.

Comment: what about using a linker (and using 'extern') ?

Comment: @Tommylee2k how would i get a linker to generate two seperate output files? i've only ever used ld for linking multiple object files into a single executable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187028/how-to-link-two-nasm-source-files

Comment: Also note that since you are in real mode and your `b.bin` is going to be loaded who knows where, you probably want far calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of possibilities. This answer focuses on a hybrid of 1 and 2. Although you can create a table of function pointers, we can use direct calls to the routines in a common library by symbol name without copying the common library routines into each program. The method I use would be to utilize the power of LD and linker scripts to create a shared library that will have a static location in memory that is accessed via FAR CALLs (segment and offset form function address) from independent programs(s) loaded elsewhere in RAM.

Most people when they start out create a linker script that produces a copy of all the input sections in the output. It is possible to create output sections that never appear (not LOADed) in the output file but the linker can still use the symbols of those nonloaded sections to resolve symbol addresses.

I've created a simple common library with a `print_banner` and `print_string` function that use BIOS functions to print to the console. Both are assumed to be called via FAR CALL's from other segments. You may have your common library loaded at 0x0100:0x0000 (physical address 0x01000) but called from code in other segments like 0x2000:0x0000 (physical address 0x20000). A sample **commlib.asm** file could look like:

```
bits 16

extern __COMMONSEG
global print_string
global print_banner
global _startcomm

section .text

; Function: print_string
;           Display a string to the console on specified display page
; Type:     FAR
;
; Inputs:   ES:SI = Offset of address to print
;           BL = Display page
; Clobbers: AX, SI
; Return:   Nothing

print_string:               ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 0x0e            ; BIOS tty Print
    jmp .getch
.repeat:
    int 0x10                ; print character
.getch:
    mov al, [es:si]         ; Get character from string
    inc si                  ; Advance pointer to next character
    test al,al              ; Have we reached end of string?
    jnz .repeat             ;     if not process next character
.end:
    retf                    ; Important: Far return

; Function: print_banner
;           Display a banner to the console to specified display page
; Type:     FAR
; Inputs:   BL = Display page
; Clobbers: AX, SI
; Return:   Nothing

print_banner:
    push es                 ; Save ES
    push cs
    pop es                  ; ES = CS
    mov si, bannermsg       ; SI = STring to print
                            ; Far call to print_string
    call __COMMONSEG:print_string
    pop es                  ; Restore ES
    retf                    ; Important: Far return

_startcomm:                 ; Keep linker quiet by defining this

section .data
bannermsg: db "Welcome to this Library!", 13, 10, 0
```

We need a linker script that allows us to create a file that we can eventually load into memory. This code assumes the segment the library will be loaded at is 0x0100 and offset 0x0000 (physical address 0x01000):

**commlib.ld**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");
ENTRY(_startcomm);

/* Common Library at 0x0100:0x0000 = physical address 0x1000 */
__COMMONSEG    = 0x0100;
__COMMONOFFSET = 0x0000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = __COMMONOFFSET;

    /* Code and data for common library at VMA = __COMMONOFFSET */
    .commlib  : SUBALIGN(4) {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.data)
        *(.bss)
    }

    /* Remove unnecessary sections */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame);
        *(.comment);
    }
}
```

It is pretty simple, it effectively links a file `commlib.o` so that it can eventually be loaded at 0x0100:0x0000. As sample program that uses this library could look like:

**prog.asm**:

```
extern __COMMONSEG
extern print_banner
extern print_string
global _start

bits 16

section .text
_start:
    mov ax, cs                   ; DS=ES=CS
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax                   ; SS:SP=CS:0x0000
    xor sp, sp

    xor bx, bx                   ; BL =  page 0 to display on
    call __COMMONSEG:print_banner; FAR Call
    mov si, mymsg                ; String to display ES:SI
    call __COMMONSEG:print_string; FAR Call

    cli
.endloop:
    hlt
    jmp .endloop

section .data
mymsg: db "Printing my own text!", 13, 10, 0
```

The trick now is to make a linker script that can take a program like this and reference the symbols in our common library without actually adding the common library code again. This can be achieved by using the `NOLOAD` type on an output section in a linker script.

**prog.ld**:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");
ENTRY(_start);

__PROGOFFSET   = 0x0000;

/* Load the commlib.elf file to access all its symbols */
INPUT(commlib.elf)

SECTIONS
{
    /* NOLOAD type prevents the actual code from being loaded into memory
       which means if you create a BINARY file from this, this section will
       not appear */
    . = __COMMONOFFSET;
    .commlib (NOLOAD) : {
        commlib.elf(.commlib);
    }

    /* Code and data for program at VMA = __PROGOFFSET */
    . = __PROGOFFSET;
    .prog : SUBALIGN(4) {
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.data)
        *(.bss)
    }

    /* Remove unnecessary sections */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame);
        *(.comment);
    }
}
```

The common library's ELF file is loaded by the linker and the `.commlib` section is marked with a `(NOLOAD)` type. This will prevent a final program from including the common library functions and data, but allows us to still reference the symbol addresses.

A simple test harness can be created as a bootloader. The bootloader will load the common library to 0x0100:0x0000 (physical address 0x01000), and the program that uses them is loaded to 0x2000:0x0000 (physical address 0x20000). The program address is arbitrary, I just picked it because it is in free memory below 1MB.

**boot.asm**:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16

start:
    ; DL = boot drive number from BIOS

    ; Set up stack and segment registers
    xor ax, ax               ; DS = 0x0000
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax               ; SS:SP=0x0000:0x7c00 below bootloader
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    cld                      ; Set direction flag forward for String instructions

    ; Reset drive
    xor ax, ax
    int 0x13

    ; Read 2nd sector (commlib.bin) to 0x0100:0x0000 = phys addr 0x01000
    mov ah, 0x02             ; Drive READ subfunction
    mov al, 0x01             ; Read one sector
    mov bx, 0x0100
    mov es, bx               ; ES=0x0100
    xor bx, bx               ; ES:BS = 0x0100:0x0000 = phys adress 0x01000
    mov cx, 0x0002           ; CH = Cylinder = 0, CL = Sector # = 2
    xor dh, dh               ; DH = Head = 0
    int 0x13

    ; Read 3rd sector (prog.bin) to 0x2000:0x0000 = phys addr 0x20000
    mov ah, 0x02             ; Drive READ subfunction
    mov al, 0x01             ; Read one sector
    mov bx, 0x2000
    mov es, bx               ; ES=0x2000
    xor bx, bx               ; ES:BS = 0x2000:0x0000 = phys adress 0x20000
    mov cx, 0x0003           ; CH = Cylinder = 0, CL = Sector # = 2
    xor dh, dh               ; DH = Head = 0
    int 0x13

    ; Jump to the entry point of our program
    jmp 0x2000:0x0000

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

After the bootloader loads the common library (sector 1) and program (sector 2) into memory it jumps to the entry point of the program at 0x2000:0x0000.

---

### Putting it All Together

We can create the file `commlib.bin` with:

```
nasm -f elf32 commlib.asm -o commlib.o
ld -melf_i386 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T commlib.ld -o commlib.elf commlib.o
objcopy -O binary commlib.elf commlib.bin
```

`commlib.elf` is also created as an intermediate file. You can create `prog.bin` with:

```
nasm -f elf32 prog.asm -o prog.o
ld -melf_i386 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T prog.ld -o prog.elf prog.o
objcopy -O binary prog.elf prog.bin
```

Create the bootloader (`boot.bin`) with:

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
```

We can build a disk image (`disk.img`) that looks like a 1.44MB floppy with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440
dd if=boot.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=0 conv=notrunc
dd if=commlib.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc
dd if=prog.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=2 conv=notrunc
```

This simple example can fit the common library and program in single sectors. I have also hard coded their locations on the disk. This is just a proof of concept, and not meant to represent your final code.

When I run this in QEMU (BOCHS will also work) using `qemu-system-i386 -fda disk.img` I get this output:

[image]

---

### Looking at prog.bin

In the example above we created a `prog.bin` file that wasn't suppose to have the common library code in it, but had symbols to it resolved. Is that what happened? If you use NDISASM you can disassemble the binary file as 16-bit code with an origin point of 0x0000 to see what was generated. Using `ndisasm -o 0x0000 -b16 prog.bin` you should see something like:

> ```
> ; Text Section
> 00000000  8CC8              mov ax,cs
> 00000002  8ED8              mov ds,ax
> 00000004  8EC0              mov es,ax
> 00000006  8ED0              mov ss,ax
> 00000008  31E4              xor sp,sp
> 0000000A  31DB              xor bx,bx
> ; Both the calls are to the function in the common library that are loaded 
> ; in a different segment at 0x0100. The linker was able to resolve these
> ; locations for us.
> 0000000C  9A14000001        call word 0x100:0x11  ; FAR Call print_banner
> 00000011  BE2000            mov si,0x20
> 00000014  9A00000001        call word 0x100:0x0   ; FAR Call print_string
> 00000019  FA                cli
> 0000001A  F4                hlt
> 0000001B  EBFD              jmp short 0x1a        ; Infinite loop
> 0000001D  6690              xchg eax,eax
> 0000001F  90                nop
> ; Data section
> ; String 'Printing my own text!', 13, 10, 0
> 00000020  50                push ax
> 00000021  7269              jc 0x8c
> 00000023  6E                outsb
> 00000024  7469              jz 0x8f
> 00000026  6E                outsb
> 00000027  67206D79          and [ebp+0x79],ch
> 0000002B  206F77            and [bx+0x77],ch
> 0000002E  6E                outsb
> 0000002F  207465            and [si+0x65],dh
> 00000032  7874              js 0xa8
> 00000034  210D              and [di],cx
> 00000036  0A00              or al,[bx+si]
> ```

I have annotated it with a few comments.

---

### Notes

- Is it required to use FAR Calls? No, but if you don't then all of your code will have to fit in a single segment and the offsets won't be able to overlap. Using FAR Calls comes with some overhead but they are more flexible allowing you to better utilize memory below 1MB. Functions called via a FAR Call have to use FAR Returns (`retf`). Far functions that use pointers passed from other segments generally need to handle segment *and* offset of pointers (FAR pointers), not just the offset.
- Using the method in this answer: anytime you make a change to the common library you have to re-link all the programs that rely on it, as the absolute memory addresses for exported (public) functions and data may shift.

Answer (score 3):

You could proceed like this:

1. Assemble and link `a.bin` to be loaded from address `0x1000`.
2. Use the `nm` utility (or similar) to dump the symbol table of `a.bin`
3. Write a script to turn the symbol  table into an assembly file `asyms.asm` that contains for each symbol in `a.bin` a line of the form

   ```
   sym EQU addr
   ```

   where `addr` is the actual address of `sym` as given by `nm`
4. Include or link `asyms.asm` when compiling `b.bin`.  This makes the addresses of the symbols in `a.bin` visible to your assembler code without pulling in the corresponding code.

What you are trying to do is known as building an *overlay.*  I believe some assemblers and linkers do have support for this sort of thing but I am not sure about the details.

Comment: GNU `ld` has an option _"-R filename, --just-symbols=filename Read symbol names and their addresses from filename, but do not relocate it or include it in the output.  This allows your output file to refer symbolically to absolute locations of memory defined in other programs."_

Comment: @Jester Such an option is indeed helpful!  You can use it to replace step (3) with `ld -r -o asyms.o -R a.elf` if `a.elf` is the ELF binary corresponding to `a.bin`.

Comment: `-R` is exactly what i'm looking for, though it is a bit finnicky because i have to do `call test_func + 0x1000` instead of just `call test_func`, i'm also not sure how well it works with segments.

Comment: @DutChen18 This indicates to me that you linked `a.bin` to the wrong address.  Make a separate post for this question if you like.  Note that the GNU linker does not support segmentation, if you want to use segmentation, you might want to use a different tool chain.

Comment: @fuz i mean in `b`, everything in `a` works fine because i'm linking it with `-Ttext 0x1000`. `b` doesn't know `a` is loaded at `0x1000` because the offset is only added at link-time, and i'm `-R`ing the not-yet-linked object file.

Comment: @DutChen18 The offsets in the object files are meaningless as relocations are applied during linking once the final load address is determined.  What you seem to do doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Please ask a separate question about this, we are leaving the scope of this question.

Comment: This wouldn't be an overlay. Overlays were code that would have shared the same space and some kind of overlay manager would swap the code in and out of a shared region. In this case the common code remains resident,it just happens to be loaded separately from the program.It is effectively a shared library with a static location.